# Bootstrap : text on two lines instead of one

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Good morning,

I use Bootstrap 4.5 and try to make a nice footer for my university site.
I use this :

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
```

In order to have my footer centered and not the blocks being far away from each other.

But, on bigger screen (i emulated it with Firefox), the text is on two lines, because of the centered option and i would like to be on one line because it had space :
[image: scrennshot]

Here is the full code if it can be helpful :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
            <h4 class="text-center">some text</h4>
            
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer_ups" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="footer_ups">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pr-2"></i>some text some text sometext sometextsome text</span>
                </a>
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">7 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
            </div>
            
            <div id="footer_ups" class="collapse pl-3" aria-labelledby="some text">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer_ipp" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="footer_ipp">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pr-2"></i>some text sometextsome text</span>
                </a>
                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">4 <i class="footer_ipp_glyph fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
            </div>
            
            <div id="footer_ipp" class="collapse pl-3" aria-labelledby="some text">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <br />
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pr-2"></i><a href="" target="_blank">some textsome textsome textsome texttextsome textsome text</a>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-4">
            <h4 class="text-center">Aide et Informations l&eacute;gales</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right pr-2"></i> <a href="" alt="" target="_blank">some text</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 text-center">
            <h4 class="text-center">Suivez-nous</h4>
            
            <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x mr-3"></i></a>
            <a href="" alt="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x mr-3"></i></a>
            <a href="" alt="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-3x mr-3"></i></a>
            <a href="" alt="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible ?

Thank you !!

Comment: I think this is not possible because your Bootstrap **col-** rules determines the column width to 50%

Comment: Seems to be an issue yes, well, too bad for me, i will live with it ^^Thank you Adam!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because you used bootstrap pre-define class **col-** to adjust width. 
If you want to convert two lines text into one class, your text will cut 
It is possible only to not to use Bootstrap class, you use custom width to all columns

Comment: Hello, thank you, that was what i suspected ! I will think of another way to do so.